# Ограничение скорости Proxy FreeBSD

Tags: ip, proxy, freebsd, squid, bsd

Здравствуйте, уважаемые! Хотел бы спросить совета. :-) Я абсолютный новичок во FreeBSD и возникла необходимость в прокси-сервере. Может, кто-то посоветует программу для ограничения скорости по ip, например? В общем, никаких дополнительных задач не нужно, только ограничение скорости пользователям. К примеру, от 1 до 10 Мбит/сек. Ещё было бы неплохо включение/отключение доступа к интернету отдельным пользователям. По тому же ip, например. Я изучил squid, но squid слишком многозадачен для таких целей. Однако, если лучшего решения нет, то буду настраивать squid. Резюмируя, вопрос в следующем: посоветуйте, пожалуйста, идеальное решение на FreeBSD для ограничения скорости пользователям и включения/отключения пользователям доступа к интернету (отключение доступа не критично). Буду благодарен. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Немного некорректная постановка вопроса. А именно - если нужно разделение канала по адресам, то прокси-сервер вообще не нужен. Прокси понадобится если нужно фильтровать (ну или что-то еще делать) с URL-ами. Таким образом, прокси и шейперы - работают на разных уровнях сетевой модели.

Для FreeBSD есть несколько решений для деления трафика (шейпинга):

- исторический `IPFW` + `DUMMYNET`
- более новый `PF` + `ALTQ`

Увы, огорчу - решений "из-коробки" как таковых нет. Придется самому искать частные решения, разбираться, писать правила под себя, под свою ситуацию. Статей в сети достаточно много. Возможно найдете даже какие-нибудь "шаблоны" для часто встречающихся ситуаций.

От себя - я бы рекомендовал начинать поиски для второго варианта, не зря же "его" портировали, когда существовал первый.

Comment: Спасибо за совет.Там есть какой-то веб-интерфейс? Например, стоял прокси на фрибсд 20-тилетней давности, его ип *.*.2.254. Был какой-то интерфейс, в который можно войти по ип *.*.2.253. Там была таблица, слева ип-шники пользователей, посередине имя, которое можно ему присвоить (типа комментарии для себя), справа выпадающим списком выбиралась скорость для этого ип-шника от 64 кб до 1 Мбита. Больше одного Мбита скорость нельзя было ставить. К сожалению, не могу посмотреть на сервере конфиги да и вообще, что это за утилита.

Comment: Нет. Этот функционал включается в ядре. Конфигурируется набором текстовых конфигов. Возможно и есть какие-то web-UI, но лично я не слышал.